# how to send background location when application terminated

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, cllocationmanager

I want to send location from back ground in every 10 minute when app is terminated or in background .
please give code and how to use it ..
is this possible if yes then suggest me 
thanks

Comment: you want send longitude and latitude ? or ?

Comment: ya latitude and longitude to server

Comment: Please help me how it can be done

Comment: wait give me some time i Will help you

Comment: Thanks.... sir i am waiting for your response ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you add the following to your header:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<CLLocationManagerDelegate>
```

Include framework:

Click your project in navigator.

**Click the plus button under "link binary with libraries"**

Add Corelocation to your project.

**Import the header file**:

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
```

**Declare CLLocationManager**:

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager;
```

ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"today monday");
    myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 60.0 target: self
                                             selector: @selector(first:) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
}

-(void)first:(id)sender
{
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    NSLog(@"called");
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
      NSString * currentLat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",coordinate.latitude];
     NSString * currentLong = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",coordinate.longitude];
    NSLog(@"latitude %@",currentLat);
    NSLog(@"longitude %@",currentLong);
}
```

NSTimer can be called first method ever 1 min

Try this i hope it's help for You

Comment: This code will run when application in background or foreground.. I want to send location when application is killed or terminated state

Comment: @ShashankPrinceMishra currentLat and currentLong values pass to Server